# how to extract the build number from the steam build page for comparing to old version using batch

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to find a way to extract the build number from the steam build page, to compare to the old version for an update script I am making using batch

The build for the public branch is after this part found on ln 1 col 5944 and ends at 5802

```
"public": {"buildid": "13585476",
```

The build ID seems to always come after the `"public": {"buildid":`

The full file. You can get this by using https://api.steamcmd.net/v1/info/%SteamGameID%

```
{"data": {"2394010": {"_change_number": 22640295, "_missing_token": false, "_sha": "a53f484e47f19ca659e1c71d5aa57d864417e986", "_size": 7299, "appid": "2394010", "common": {"associations": {}, "clienticon": "22a20bdaa6d782f60caa45eb7b02fc2411dcd988", "clienttga": "2032a63848f1ab00b518b7e984bd533c1ce0cf07", "gameid": "2394010", "icon": "606e637a2f0610f3805893e917c0e22d1d043ba6", "linuxclienticon": "d26e2c064a36a71a1ae404a0fc9bef6c2182f611", "name": "Palworld Dedicated Server", "osarch": "64", "osextended": "", "oslist": "windows,linux", "parent": "1623730", "releasestate": "released", "type": "Tool"}, "config": {"installdir": "PalServer", "launch": {"0": {"arguments": "-useperfthreads -NoAsyncLoadingThread -UseMultithreadForDS", "config": {"oslist": "windows"}, "executable": "PalServer.exe", "type": "default"}, "1": {"arguments": "EpicApp=PalServer -useperfthreads -NoAsyncLoadingThread -UseMultithreadForDS -publiclobby", "config": {"oslist": "linux"}, "executable": "PalServer.sh", "type": "default"}, "2": {"arguments": "-publiclobby -useperfthreads -NoAsyncLoadingThread -UseMultithreadForDS -publiclobby", "description": "Open and start as a community server", "description_loc": {"english": "Open and start as a community server"}, "executable": "PalServer.exe"}}}, "depots": {"1004": {"config": {"oslist": "windows"}, "depotfromapp": "1007", "manifests": {"public": {"download": "13804528", "gid": "1923798258558304932", "size": "44194776"}}}, "1005": {"config": {"oslist": "macos"}, "depotfromapp": "1007", "manifests": {"public": {"download": "0", "gid": "2135359612286175146", "size": "0"}}}, "1006": {"config": {"oslist": "linux"}, "depotfromapp": "1007", "manifests": {"public": {"download": "20270768", "gid": "4884950798805348056", "size": "73781292"}}}, "228989": {"config": {"oslist": "windows"}, "depotfromapp": "228980", "sharedinstall": "1"}, "2394011": {"config": {"osarch": "64", "oslist": "windows"}, "encryptedmanifests": {"main_development": {"download": "341FA01F9A87AD891BA3709EAFB9A7E6", "gid": "FE9CA32D71E548C25B1EBB4A24DFC5E7", "size": "C5BBA3F56B0BCA37774475F6EDCD6CB9"}, "main_shipping": {"download": "610DC1B95EADDC9C91DF8134231538C4", "gid": "5ED9E008B260439F1D1A43609558C967", "size": "3F8B2BC51DFEC0F7FA16D681DFBBD91E"}, "main_test": {"download": "592660B08414491EB6D96370DF42158A", "gid": "4E7680D483F0E28EE3E0ECAEF9991A93", "size": "CAADBAF84ADD02975621E610827B1638"}, "network_development": {"download": "DBE5538D1DEA6D0C10EE0054614FBB57", "gid": "2338407EB8ACAD99DA90CE5F4A0F86F3", "size": "41D370410D056EAEED1A127F0F8823E3"}, "network_test": {"download": "6452A19273C8CF809D3D1800F116CF00", "gid": "8A82B817F933C870266A79E2AA0345D7", "size": "F70FF4142E90B7FA34C4A536D65B2C22"}, "private_development": {"download": "D7276975F8C8B53B508882EBB3B40618", "gid": "A30D9A1E29AD71D3C37E49828F3A190D", "size": "47C01C7FABCD626EAFB48C47AC29B930"}, "private_shipping": {"download": "B8AAF1B532A86E41F89964CF4BD3F43A", "gid": "F97AC8AD4BA0AA632F61C873DBC64B35", "size": "BC4DE2102642AFF2F45FAC54FE97693C"}, "private_test": {"download": "0AA9FF39E3132D7EFA973E99FD4D889E", "gid": "B5B2B88312687534C8F1B80017C76071", "size": "1D5E544819961A033AA160D72B248A34"}, "qa_development": {"download": "4D53D9A9132F852382DF8DC133FA01FA", "gid": "CE6AAD76E2838708E977B087A6862450", "size": "76BD9BB88B98FA27C6E8859310A5DA4B"}, "qa_test": {"download": "BBD773C3CBB007BF410823A4A479812C", "gid": "4FA6EEA7176D5497935E8DAC6DC8521D", "size": "3D5A6671D63CF35AE677F4960666DD52"}}, "manifests": {"public": {"download": "1817329616", "gid": "3909453160250477875", "size": "2634379082"}}}, "2394012": {"config": {"osarch": "64", "oslist": "linux"}, "encryptedmanifests": {"main_development": {"download": "CAA40DFB627C248E2B861C1A959B78A0", "gid": "C4B345F653E69D3A8D824B3BDCDF6E45", "size": "FDD9D947C6EE76F4B043B013A4EC8578"}, "main_shipping": {"download": "0637954CC4E1D3839705757210554002", "gid": "493D3221D9FD8EA90B453139F508965D", "size": "9D879F3A6F3686B5B3FAA8DE4B9C80E8"}, "main_test": {"download": "A5BF2F1DA37AA157900E9FB4423DE1AB", "gid": "2BFBF75618C682A2438F19E21B298263", "size": "19B92E209D5C2465D5DA4F1E82D2C76C"}, "network_development": {"download": "7CDB8D38354AF29FE19A1FB94BBF2902", "gid": "879E66D8EC6DE5683690429053175379", "size": "9A65782E2232060642D92271F5EC695A"}, "network_test": {"download": "9F0239BB70A1ADA0A24E78301F93FB33", "gid": "B8EA804B5ACA6856F0735038597E6CC0", "size": "F24EA35AC6987754788924BADECB39B9"}, "private_development": {"download": "692ABD6B9472B5A1D143ADA52EDE5334", "gid": "6DE562F362D22CA783D022757067F78B", "size": "8A2F1FE55B244C3472FF0A049A9C86F2"}, "private_test": {"download": "A9E09B6BF978C5BB07CB08A143B487C9", "gid": "317EE013A2FF2D90CAD8BE7D9C420B5F", "size": "B901FB67C3C0BBAA273DD2E85B696B45"}, "qa_development": {"download": "C732C52909434FCB875C53A88C013DFA", "gid": "504868BEFC6BEE793B90919E672CC3E1", "size": "8CEF75E9C0AF17DEBECDABDE7E63C490"}, "qa_test": {"download": "57C6D3EE16B08BB0688FEC9BBCE8F58E", "gid": "8ED372EE2B84DB361561EBB6C5ED35AF", "size": "103A73CA89295C0A46563FFD4AE9DA0C"}}, "manifests": {"public": {"download": "1708620368", "gid": "2815085007637542021", "size": "2187203282"}}}, "branches": {"main_development": {"buildid": "13644213", "pwdrequired": "1", "timeupdated": "1709634739"}, "main_shipping": {"buildid": "13644092", "pwdrequired": "1", "timeupdated": "1709633869"}, "main_test": {"buildid": "13644302", "pwdrequired": "1", "timeupdated": "1709635395"}, "network_development": {"buildid": "13162989", "pwdrequired": "1", "timeupdated": "1705119306"}, "network_test": {"buildid": "13162940", "pwdrequired": "1", "timeupdated": "1705118469"}, "private_development": {"buildid": "13646268", "pwdrequired": "1", "timeupdated": "1709647875"}, "private_shipping": {"buildid": "12344676", "pwdrequired": "1", "timeupdated": "1696342174"}, "private_test": {"buildid": "13646174", "pwdrequired": "1", "timeupdated": "1709647293"}, "public": {"buildid": "13585476", "timeupdated": "1709170119"}, "qa_development": {"buildid": "13585483", "pwdrequired": "1", "timeupdated": "1709607496"}, "qa_test": {"buildid": "13585476", "pwdrequired": "1", "timeupdated": "1709607431"}}}, "extended": {"gamedir": "Palworld", "serverbrowsername": "Palworld"}}}, "status": "success"}
```

Most of the things I have tried have not worked, doing searching for a word and then one after has not worked as there are multiple BuildID's in the file and I have not been able to search for "public": {"buildid": " then gotten the build Id after that

~edit
bigger files for testing

9267k file

```
{"data": {"376030": {"_change_number": 20584871, "_missing_token": false, "_sha": "abc6c7bde5e8dc8075d92802ae004c1b0eee5d45", "_size": 10869, "appid": "376030", "common": {"associations": {}, "gameid": "376030", "name": "ARK: Survival Evolved Dedicated Server", "oslist": "windows,linux", "releasestate": "released", "section_type": "ownersonly", "type": "Tool"}, "config": {"contenttype": "3", "installdir": "ARK Survival Evolved Dedicated Server", "launch": {"0": {"arguments": "TheIsland?listen ", "config": {"oslist": "windows"}, "description": "Launch (Map: TheIsland)", "executable": "ShooterGame\\Binaries\\Win64\\ShooterGameServer.exe", "type": "none"}, "1": {"arguments": "TheIsland?listen -UseBattlEye", "config": {"oslist": "windows"}, "description": "Launch (Map: TheIsland, With BattlEye Anticheat)", "executable": "ShooterGame\\Binaries\\Win64\\ShooterGameServer.exe", "type": "none"}, "10": {"arguments": "TheCenter?listen -UseBattlEye", "config": {"oslist": "linux"}, "description": "Launch (Map: TheCenter, With BattlEye Anticheat)", "executable": "ShooterGame/Binaries/Linux/ShooterGame", "type": "none"}, "11": {"arguments": "TheIsland?listen -TotalConversionMod=111111111", "config": {"oslist": "linux"}, "description": "Launch (Map: TheIsland, Total Conversion: Primitive+)", "executable": "ShooterGame/Binaries/Linux/ShooterGame", "type": "none"}, "12": {"arguments": "TheIsland?listen -TotalConversionMod=111111111 -UseBattlEye", "config": {"oslist": "linux"}, "description": "Launch (Map: TheIsland, Primitive+, With BattlEye Anticheat)", "executable": "ShooterGame/Binaries/Linux/ShooterGame", "type": "none"}, "2": {"arguments": "TheCenter?listen", "config": {"oslist": "windows"}, "description": "Launch (Map: TheCenter)", "executable": "ShooterGame\\Binaries\\Win64\\ShooterGameServer.exe", "type": "none"}, "3": {"arguments": "TheCenter?listen -UseBattlEye", "config": {"oslist": "windows"}, "description": "Launch (Map: TheCenter, With BattlEye Anticheat)", "executable": "ShooterGame\\Binaries\\Win64\\ShooterGameServer.exe", "type": "none"}, "4": {"arguments": "TheIsland?listen -TotalConversionMod=111111111", "config": {"oslist": "windows"}, "description": "Launch (Map: TheIsland, Total Conversion: Primitive+)", "executable": "ShooterGame\\Binaries\\Win64\\ShooterGameServer.exe", "type": "none"}, "5": {"arguments": "TheIsland?listen -TotalConversionMod=111111111 -UseBattlEye", "config": {"oslist": "windows"}, "description": "Launch (Map: TheIsland, Primitive+, With BattlEye Anticheat)", "executable": "ShooterGame\\Binaries\\Win64\\ShooterGameServer.exe", "type": "none"}, "6": {"arguments": "TheIsland?listen ", "config": {"oslist": "linux"}, "description": "Launch (Map: TheIsland)", "executable": "ShooterGame/Binaries/Linux/ShooterGame", "type": "none"}, "7": {"arguments": "TheIsland?listen -UseBattlEye", "config": {"oslist": "linux"}, "description": "Launch (Map: TheIsland, With BattlEye Anticheat)", "executable": "ShooterGame/Binaries/Linux/ShooterGame", "type": "none"}, "8": {"arguments": "TheCenter?listen", "config": {"oslist": "linux"}, "description": "Launch (Map: TheCenter)", "executable": "ShooterGame/Binaries/Linux/ShooterGame", "type": "none"}, "9": {"arguments": "TheCenter?listen", "config": {"oslist": "linux"}, "description": "Launch (Map: TheCenter, With BattlEye Anticheat)", "executable": "ShooterGame/Binaries/Linux/ShooterGame", "type": "none"}}}, "depots": {"1004": {"config": {"oslist": "windows"}, "depotfromapp": "1007", "manifests": {"public": {"download": "13804528", "gid": "1923798258558304932", "size": "44194776"}}}, "1005": {"config": {"oslist": "macos"}, "depotfromapp": "1007", "manifests": {"public": {"download": "0", "gid": "2135359612286175146", "size": "0"}}}, "1006": {"config": {"oslist": "linux"}, "depotfromapp": "1007", "manifests": {"public": {"download": "20270768", "gid": "4884950798805348056", "size": "73781292"}}}, "376031": {"encryptedmanifests": {"arklive": {"download": "E20B84A4FA2EE8FBEE9C5560F8375EAB", "gid": "57A7D0892CF67B0886E4B1113E90971D", "size": "75505A086C374C2E3A778FE3B5736B4B"}, "dev2test": {"download": "EA10F02C4DACC67762E35F08DA9F1DDD", "gid": "DAB9199FF624449276CA647101528DEC", "size": "D2629D1C87EC4B2C75403E223E5EFDEA"}, "devtest": {"download": "3F09BE8398726252F31C4DBBE97EC4DC", "gid": "2E8D216FDF14776C902561C3F746AD15", "size": "1FEF46C5F676488E40D8186DEC39028C"}, "devtest2_beta": {"download": "01DA6AC472C6C3B43EF5356DA28A50C2", "gid": "C27FAE3193593E56B09128F727334AC8", "size": "5D66025BE2BAF8B75CD6369536CD2555"}, "devtest3_beta": {"download": "6E45B2CF1F1F98CCB4869864752FEE5C", "gid": "049D43607A1BA47E65C885991A6FB6B1", "size": "E22D347BE00886832C119EE15D5B6860"}, "devtest_beta": {"download": "95B77779E26A352B4EC5734E92297DEB", "gid": "9129DF3B7DCABBD05ACE5F6BB54146FC", "size": "D16D5034A39D83EB9A99B18D8412B868"}, "eventtemp": {"download": "78980AB1C13B40ADA88A3FFD794AC18E", "gid": "2FB380026F03B748DA2E5C271097F107", "size": "5F580147F2EEA945C7457F605723C7A0"}, "family": {"download": "604DCC48426DD57BF1513AC81027D0BB", "gid": "8C96304439BC2D5F26A1A21930E6353E", "size": "0783205D33DB907AC17749B92F7FE6A4"}, "friedcheese": {"download": "B96080182114A1069297B877098C3A5D", "gid": "BD02E0C21451034D048D59EFABB43B29", "size": "EEFD0E1F67D0A5541B4AC0223C931286"}, "hotfix3": {"download": "111FCE68790154779D51A0FA37D46002", "gid": "F3977CCA9110D3A241F5CFB6690982F9", "size": "6BEAA6EB0E5B63A5AB71913AA9FE92C8"}, "hungryman": {"download": "6D2840CEAA7569F20F9998DA7D0B1CE9", "gid": "5F60B3C7D3599B40A63B59E8FAA62718", "size": "59BB03D637EE90EEED44E02199D42EA7"}, "kidcuisine": {"download": "3429260C17364751F483DAC1DAE04CE4", "gid": "1F2432ECD7BC9A7DEE6939AD446DE80C", "size": "C96D8298C8498622C80A671C170BB7A5"}, "lemonbar": {"download": "D7D12B00D8318A50CE74D8730407CBC1", "gid": "4F9262B109F60E02E3D304DCD6FA5256", "size": "9D8E2B29F6A8230CE7E4F9267F0FD62C"}, "lemonbar_m": {"download": "E71471BEC992B9B85F4DD425DAE56C55", "gid": "00013B7D88EF7333BE66CCADE5A55FDC", "size": "3A8ADA77F66551EEB7B82555B10EAA84"}, "lemonbar_s": {"download": "873D956FE3170A886E1BE39DAB8F50A0", "gid": "7BF27781F6FECBD1359FC80CE1F3AC60", "size": "635F2879FD26EA9BD7B843477DDC561A"}, "nitradotesting": {"download": "3C1A1C6F017B6593147E4AD932E6419D", "gid": "DFD6AE76021941F2CBD66325D8DA1A64", "size": "DB526AE1AEBC75281A8E60AF6BFB9BA9"}, "servertestbackup_s": {"download": "23186A035E6A29AF4411A7FE06827773", "gid": "FC649F0AE9449EADEB0B31072682F534", "size": "D74D8A4A5BED4BA577B0F850B1F308A1"}, "threepp": {"download": "28457FE0A7CB2432F4E089009DF114D8", "gid": "49CC78D8F4CB02186F8CB173C705A032", "size": "F30EE78F4AD41BB25F68FC3E484A9A2C"}, "threepx": {"download": "3F7CF0A7FDC109980ED1B04D29BDF5CD", "gid": "9BB7A8434CFECB99154B963F488E072D", "size": "1EFC2EF95AFBDEC12A768ECAD5C5F8E0"}, "trailer": {"download": "0D75257F999EED6E99E32D5111279AD2", "gid": "4376F55746FA3998A5ECFD09A0A088C5", "size": "5B23877661B4456E0C4D01C91B1FBBD5"}}, "manifests": {"experimental": {"download": "3138319952", "gid": "4938714156080904010", "size": "9076395353"}, "public": {"download": "6578702464", "gid": "3873896756387355933", "size": "18775925629"}, "timecapsule": {"download": "6740753408", "gid": "385619103637186563", "size": "18742658083"}}}, "376032": {}, "branches": {"arklive": {"buildid": "12291776", "pwdrequired": "1", "timeupdated": "1696032040"}, "dev2test": {"buildid": "11925632", "pwdrequired": "1", "timeupdated": "1692027882"}, "devtest": {"buildid": "11925756", "pwdrequired": "1", "timeupdated": "1692027904"}, "devtest2_beta": {"buildid": "12380143", "pwdrequired": "1", "timeupdated": "1696643835"}, "devtest3_beta": {"buildid": "3409246", "pwdrequired": "1", "timeupdated": "1545151414"}, "devtest_beta": {"buildid": "12291970", "pwdrequired": "1", "timeupdated": "1695785139"}, "eventtemp": {"buildid": "10084159", "pwdrequired": "1", "timeupdated": "1671227853"}, "experimental": {"buildid": "4205769", "timeupdated": "1568824771"}, "family": {"buildid": "10173941", "pwdrequired": "1", "timeupdated": "1671414897"}, "friedcheese": {"buildid": "10180269", "pwdrequired": "1", "timeupdated": "1671504919"}, "hotfix3": {"buildid": "10186624", "pwdrequired": "1", "timeupdated": "1671561851"}, "hungryman": {"buildid": "12291776", "pwdrequired": "1", "timeupdated": "1695782598"}, "kidcuisine": {"buildid": "11924389", "pwdrequired": "1", "timeupdated": "1691783008"}, "lemonbar": {"buildid": "11373375", "pwdrequired": "1", "timeupdated": "1685647547"}, "lemonbar_m": {"buildid": "12291970", "pwdrequired": "1", "timeupdated": "1695847539"}, "lemonbar_s": {"buildid": "12380143", "pwdrequired": "1", "timeupdated": "1696643912"}, "nitradotesting": {"buildid": "6804751", "pwdrequired": "1", "timeupdated": "1622710853"}, "public": {"buildid": "12291776", "timeupdated": "1696032099"}, "servertestbackup_s": {"buildid": "10473490", "pwdrequired": "1", "timeupdated": "1675886386"}, "threepp": {"buildid": "11925632", "pwdrequired": "1", "timeupdated": "1692036195"}, "threepx": {"buildid": "11925756", "pwdrequired": "1", "timeupdated": "1692036209"}, "timecapsule": {"buildid": "5131177", "timeupdated": "1591494821"}, "trailer": {"buildid": "11380229", "pwdrequired": "1", "timeupdated": "1685715177"}}}}}, "status": "success"}
```

if you use curl https://api.steamcmd.net/v1/info/107410
you can get a 88003 k file

Comment: 95% of the time, people who post on batch questions to recommend powershell are only doing so because they suck at batch, but parsing JSON (_especially_ as a single line) absolutely calls for powershell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a hybrid batch file and jscript originally created by user npocmaka.
[You can get here on Gitub.](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/jsonextractor.bat)

I have modified the script for it to prompt for input and run the curl command to get the json from the api.

```
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then

@echo off & setlocal
set /p "gameid=Enter GameID number:"
curl -s -X GET "https://api.steamcmd.net/v1/info/%gameid%" -o "%gameid%.json"
cscript /nologo /e:JScript "%~f0" "%gameid%.json" "data[%gameid%].depots.branches.public.buildid"

REM DO NOT EDIT BELOW THIS LINE!!!
goto :EOF

@end // end batch / begin JScript hybrid chimera

var htmlfile = WSH.CreateObject('htmlfile');
htmlfile.write('<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=9" />');
var JSON = htmlfile.parentWindow.JSON;

//needs file existence checks
var jsloc=WScript.Arguments.Item(0);
var jsonPath=WScript.Arguments.Item(1);


FSOObj = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
var txtFile=FSOObj.OpenTextFile(jsloc,1);
var json=txtFile.ReadAll();

try {
    var jParsed=JSON.parse(json);
}catch(err) {
   WScript.Echo("Failed to parse the json content");
   htmlfile.close();
   txtFile.close();
   WScript.Exit(1);
   //WScript.Echo(err.message);
}
WScript.Echo(eval("JSON.stringify(jParsed."+jsonPath+")"));

htmlfile.close();
txtFile.close();
```

Running the script asks you for the game id. Executes the curl command to get the json from the API. It then uses the jscript portion of the script to parse the json and display the public build id.

```
D:\BatchFiles\json>hybrid.bat
Enter GameID number:2394010
"13585476"
```

Comment: I am not sure what I am doing wrong with this one when I test it it runs and asks for the id but then just closes

Comment: @Mr_Galaxy, first two rules of debugging a batch file. 1) Open up a command prompt and run the batch file from their. DO NOT USE YOUR MOUSE! 2) IF needed, turn ECHO ON at the top of your batch file to see each line of code execute. This allows you to see any errors.

Comment: got it working thanks, bit of the code must have been cut off
`WScript.Echo(eval("JSON.stringify(jParsed."+jsonPath+")"));
htmlfile.close();
txtFile.close();`
thank you for your help

Comment: @Mr_Galaxy, my apologies.  That is my bad.  I updated the answer with the missing three lines.

Comment: could the file then output to a file? like a txt

Comment: That is basic [redirection](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/redirection.php) of standard output.

Answer (score 1):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion
rem The following settings for the directory and filename are names
rem that I use for testing and deliberately includes spaces to make sure
rem that the process works using such names. These will need to be changed to suit your situation.

SET "sourcedir=u:\your files"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q78118427.txt"

SET "public="
SET "buildid="
SET "required="

FOR /f "usebackqdelims=" %%e IN ("%filename1%") DO (
 SET "line=%%e"
 SET "line=!line::= !"
 SET "line=!line:{= !"
 SET "line=!line:}= !"
 FOR %%y IN (!line!) DO (
  IF DEFINED public IF DEFINED buildid IF NOT DEFINED required SET "required=%%~y"
  IF "%%~y"=="public" (SET "public=Y"&SET "buildid=") ELSE (
   IF "%%~y"=="buildid" (
    IF DEFINED public (SET "buildid=Y") ELSE (SET "public="&SET "buildid=")
   ) ELSE (SET "public="&SET "buildid=")
  )
 )
)

ECHO required data: "%required%"

GOTO :EOF
```

Note that if the filename does not contain separators like spaces, then both `usebackq` and the quotes around `%filename1%` can be  omitted.

Grab the line of data that appears in `%%e` and record as `line`.

Replace each `:`, `{` and `}` with a space using `delayedexpansion` as you cannot manipulate `%%e` directly. This yields a string that can be processed as a series of space-or-comma-separated tokens.

Each dequoted token is compared to the two key strings. Only if the sequence `public` `buildid` is found will both the variables `public` and `buildid` be set to non-empty (ie. "defined")

We need the string that occurs directly after thos two flags are set.

Comment: Magoo some of the json output is one long line that exceeds 8,192 characters.  Which it the cmd max length.

Comment: @Squashman : Yes - the 8K limit would no doubt be significant, in which case a utility like `sed` or `(g)awk` could be pressed into service to support `cmd`. Depends on any policies to which OP may be subject. The code worked with OP's data which was a 6,280 byte file. Granted, I only tested it to ~5802 bytes, but that exceeds the intuitive 4K limit for concatenated variables. I believe the saver is that all references to any value in a var that might be excessively long are either `%%e` or `!var!`. More than ~8K in the file, and Danger, Will Robinson!

Comment: when I test this code I get the main_development branch not public

Comment: Fixed to clear both flags if token which is neither public nor buildid

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
@echo off
setlocal
   
for /F "delims=" %%a in (test.txt) do set "line=%%a" & goto continue
:continue
for /F "delims=," %%a in ("%line:*"public": {"buildid": =%") do set "buildID=%%a"
echo %buildID%
```

After read the first line, remove from the beginning until the `"public": {"buildid":`  part; then, get the first token.

Output:

```
"13585476"
```

Comment: For some of the games the output is well over 8,192 characters long.  Will that not exceed a batch files cmd line limitation?

Comment: @Squashman: Of course! In such a case, the file must be read using [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30207948/778560). However, in this case I rely on the OP specification: _"The build for the public branch is after this part found on ln 1 col 5944 and ends at 5802"_ that, of course, was confirmed by me before write any code...

Comment: In this instance it is inside the 8,192 characters.  But in my testing  I did see some of the games had the build id outside 8,192.

Comment: I was testing with `251570`.  The public build id is at position 18,763.

Comment: is there a way to get the `"public": {"buildid": "13585476",` if it is more than 8,192 characters long

Comment: @Mr_Galaxy: Please, post a longer data file so I can do some tests... After that, advice me via a comment here

Comment: @Aacini added to the bottom there is also a link for an 88003k file would be nice to read that but prob way too big, but there is a 9267k file to

Comment: @Aacini, just use the CURL command from my code to download game id 251570. `curl -s -X GET "https://api.steamcmd.net/v1/info/251570" -o "251570.json"`